# incrementing with two instead of one

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am building a website with CodeIgniter, and I ran into a problem:

When I load the view of the song page I also want to update in database the view count by one, but it is updating by two. I don't understand why, this happens, because when I try the same method when the download button is pressed to update the download count, that one works fine.

Here is the code:

```
function view($slug) {
    // Get the song from database by slug
    $data['song'] = $this->mdl_song->get_where_row("slug", $slug);        


    // if thre is a song, continue
    if ($data['song']) {
        // Set data to send to the view file
        $data['module'] = "song";
        $data['view_file'] = "single";
        $data['page_title'] = "Download {$data['song']->name}";
        // echo the template that display the view
        echo Modules::run('template/two_col', $data);
        // Update the song hits 
        $this->mdl_song->_update($data['song']->id, array('hits' => $data['song']->hits + 1));
    } else {
        show_404();
    }
}

function _update($id, $data) {     
    $table = $this->get_table();

    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update($table);
}
```

Comment: is it possible you're updating using a get request and the browser is firing one (Prefetching) the page ? This would explain the issue.

Comment: what do you get by doing var_dump($data['song']); ??

Comment: is it possible the function is being called twice

Comment: Show `Mdl_song.php` code that goes before issuing action.